# Why am I managing two versions of a Django static file?

Tags: django, django-staticfiles

I'm still confused by some Django static file management and have a suspicion I'm doing something wrong/stupid. I have a core css file -

```
/app/static/base.css
```

But for some reason, cannot recall why, I also have -

```
/static/css/base.css
```

Here's everything in my settings file that I think relates to static files:

```
PROJECT_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    BASE_DIR+'/other_app_1/static/',
    BASE_DIR+'/other_app_2/static/',
    BASE_DIR+'/app/static/',
)

STATICFILES_LOCATION = 'static'
# uncomment and run collect static before pushing to live - python manage.py collectstatic
# remember to change back for when you continue to develop
#STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'custom_storages.StaticStorage'
```

I've pasted that as it might reveal why I originally started doing this, there has to be a reason.

Am I correct in thinking I can stop updating /static/css/base.css and simply use the other one? I can't recall why I started, but I'm sorry to say that I still find Django static file management very confusing.

Comment: It is stupidly confusing! Why not move each one of the .css files in turn to another folder and see if/when Django spits up errors about being unable to access the required file?

Comment: @HaydenEastwood thanks, glad it's not just me. Will give that a go.

Comment: Good luck - I've been using Django for 5+ years and I still don't get static directories, and I'm way too bored by it to spend time figuring it out. I just copy what I did previously and replicate that which causes no errors. It's definitely a weakness in Django. I hope future versions have this aspect better thought out.

Comment: @HaydenEastwood It's /app/static/base.css that leads to the errors in the browser. So you can't think of a reason why I would be doubling up? Sounds like I should delete one of them and move on.

Answer (score 0):

```
    STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    STATIC_ROOT,
)
```

just replace BASE_URL inside STATICFILES_URL with STATIC_ROOT

Comment: Thanks Romil - would you be able to explain a little bit more about why this solves the problem?

Comment: STATIC_ROOT is the folder where static files will be stored after using manage.py collectstatic     STATICFILES_DIRS is the list of folders where Django will search for additional static files aside from the static folder of each app installed.